# Error : conversion from string "C/user/mydocument" to type boolean is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Vb App which saves data on my document 
I have Console_Load program which creates 2 TXT file and validates the same as other fragment of codes looks for the same TXT files but when i install this app post publish it throws an error on Console load "Error : conversion from string "C/user/mydocument" to type boolean is not valid"

Below are the code:-

```
Dim chkuser As String
        Dim chkpass As String
        Dim LoadUser As String
        Dim LoadPass As String
        Dim userexist As Boolean
        Dim passexist As Boolean
        Dim fullFilePathu As String
        Dim fullFilePathp As String
        With My.Computer.FileSystem
            fullFilePathu = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")
            fullFilePathp = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")
            If fullFilePathp = False Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fullFilePathu, String.Empty, False)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fullFilePathp, String.Empty, False)
            End If
            chkpass = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "pass.txt")
            chkuser = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("chkpass", String.Empty, False)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("chkuser", String.Empty, False)
            LoadUser = .ReadAllText(chkuser)
            LoadPass = .ReadAllText(chkpass)
            userexist = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(chkuser)
            passexist = My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(chkpass)
            If userexist = True Then
                UserName.Text = LoadUser
                PASSWORD.Text = LoadPass
                LOGIN.Enabled = False
                AutoON.Enabled = False
                statusIO.Text = "Logged In"
                LOGIN.Enabled = False
                LOGOFF.Enabled = True
```

PS i am a newbie
Thanks in advance

Comment: With My.Computer.FileSystem
            fullFilePathu = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")
            fullFilePathp = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")
            If fullFilePathp = False Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fullFilePathu, String.Empty, False)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fullFilePathp, String.Empty, False)
            End If
            chkpass = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "pass.txt")
            chkuser = .CombinePath(.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "user.txt")

Comment: `fullFilePathp = ...` assigns a string.  `If fullFilePathp = False Then` a string cannot be true or false.  what are you trying to do?  `With My.Computer.FileSystem` is pretty wonky too

Comment: `userexist = True` is redundant. It can be shortened to `userexist`. For example: `If userexist Then`. Not related to the exception though. Perhaps you can use a Try...Catch and report the stack trace so we can see on which line the exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the True and false statement, the exception occurs on teh code i mentioned above i am sure but not sure why, The intention is if there is a TXT file named user it will not create any file or it will create a txt file called user.tst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Plutonix points out, Line #12:

```
If fullFilePathp = False Then
```

is causing the exception since a string cannot be compared to a Boolean. Try changing it to

```
If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fullFilePathp) Then
```

Hopefully this won't be too wonky. ;-)

Comment: That worked out like a charm Thanks a lot Jerry and Plutonix